# How to count the number of times a string appears in a range of cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
 <br>1<br>text <br>2<br>text <br>3<br>
 <br>4<br>
 <br>5<br>text <br>6<br>text <br>7<br>text <br>8<br>
```

What is the formula to count the number of times  `<br>*<br>`  appears in this table A1:A3? Keep in mind there is a space in the front of each cell.

The total count should be 8. `=COUNTIF(A1:A3," <br>*<br>")` only returns 3 however.

Edit: Have made data simpler so it is easier to read

Comment: It returns 3 because there are 3 rows

Comment: @MohsenAlyafei I have also tried =(LEN(A1:A3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A3, " <br>*<br>","")))/LEN(" <br>*<br>")  however it returns 0

Comment: countif returns the number of cells (not the number of occurrence of the string)

Answer (score 1):

This Microsoft documentation link can help you out with multiple variations of what you're trying to achieve - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/formulas-to-count-occurrences-in-excel

To count the occurrences of a substring in a range of cells, you can use this:

`SUM(LEN(range)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(range,"text","")))/LEN("text")`

If the above does not work for you you can try this:

[image]

Numbers:

[image]

To count the occurrences of a substring in **one** cell, a combination of formulas in excel will do the trick.

Short answer (just plug in your specific text or cell references into this):

```
=(LEN("original_text")-LEN(SUBSTITUTE("original_text","text_to_count","")))/LEN("text_to_count")
```

Long answer if you're interested:

1. SUBSTITUTE(x, y, z) - takes the original text (x) and the text you want to find (y) and replaces all occurrences of y in x with z and returns the string. In your case (I've chosen a smaller string for brevity):

`=SUBSTITUTE("123331<br>asdsdas <br>","<br>","")`

This will substitute all occurrences of 
 with an empty string in your original string - 123331asdsdas

2. LEN(x) - simply returns length of the x. In your case:

`=LEN(SUBSTITUTE("123331<br>asdsdas <br>","<br>",""))`

This will return 14 which is the length of 123331asdsdas.

3. `=LEN("123331<br>asdsdas <br>")` which gives you 22.
4. `=LEN("123331<br>asdsdas <br>") - LEN(SUBSTITUTE("123331<br>asdsdas <br>","<br>",""))` which **subtracts length of the substituted string from length of the original string** giving you 8.
5. `(LEN("123331<br>asdsdas <br>") - LEN(SUBSTITUTE("123331<br>asdsdas <br>","<br>","")))/LEN("<br>")` divides the above answer from the subtraction by the length of your original string, giving you **2**.

> This is the number of times 
>  occurred in one cell.

6. In plain English, we did `(length_of_original_string - length_of_substituted_string)/length_of_string_to_find` which translates to `(22-14)/4 = 2` in your case.

Comment: It seems LEN(range) isn't working on Excel for Mac OS atleast. Unsure about windows. If it doesn't work for you you can calculate the lengths individually and then sum them up. That'll work.

Comment: What I am trying to find, is the text in between the first <br> with a space in front and up until/including the second <br>. If you highlight the first formula you will see that there are spaces in front of the data in each cell, and spaces in front of some of the <br> strings inside the cell. The number groups in the original question are the total, so 8. Your answer seems to ignore the spaces

Comment: I imagine you would need a **mid** function for that.

Comment: My bad, I didn't understand your question right. You need the occurrences of space<br>num<br> If you do know VBA, you can easily do this using Regular Expressions.

Comment: This might be helpful if you're willing to go the VBA route - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops

Comment: I believe the your first formula always works in this case: `=SUMPRODUCT(INT((LEN(A1:A3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A3,"<br>","")))/LEN("<br>")/2))`

Answer (score 1):

This seems like XML/HTML so why not parse it through `FILTERXML` with a `XPATH` construct to count values that do ***not*** contain a space and are ***not*** empty. For example with your data in `A1`:

```
=COUNTA(FILTERXML("<t><br>"&SUBSTITUTE(CONCAT(A1:A3),"<br>","</br><br>")&"</br></t>","//br[not(contains(., ' '))][node()]"))
```

Or when your valid data could hold spaces we would need to filter out the ones that end with a space (and the empty ones again):

```
=COUNTA(FILTERXML("<t><br>"&SUBSTITUTE(CONCAT(A1:A3),"<br>","</br><br>")&"</br></t>","//br[not(substring(., string-length(.), 1)=' ')][node()]"))
```

If however what you are after are the numeric nodes only to count then use:

```
=COUNT(FILTERXML("<t><br>"&SUBSTITUTE(CONCAT(A1:A3),"<br>","</br><br>")&"</br></t>","//br[.*0=0]"))
```

The cool thing is `FILTERXML` will actually return an array for further analyses, in your case you can count the elements in the array.

Comment: Suggest replacing `A1` with `CONCAT(A1:A3)`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, `A1:A3` was right in my face and I didn't notice it. Thanks for the extra eye.

Answer (score 1):

Or,

In B1 enter formula :

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(A1:A3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A3," ","")))
```

[image]